# Existence of weak solution via Schauder's fixed point theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems, nonlinear-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be open and bounded, $f\in L^{2}(\Omega)$ and let $a : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous such that $\alpha_{1} \le a(s) \le \alpha_2$ for every $s\in \mathbb{R}$, where $0<\alpha_1 <\alpha_2<\infty $. Prove that there exists a weak solution $u \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ to the boundary value problem $$\begin{cases}
-\text{div}\left(a\left(u\right)\nabla u\right)=f & \text{in}\ \Omega\\
u=0 & \text{on}\ \partial\Omega
\end{cases}$$

I know that there is a solution using Schauder's fixed point theorem , but I cannot fill all the details at the moment .

Comment: It would improve your Question to add context.  For example, sketch the details of applying the fixed point theorem which you are able to fill in.  Your title suggests a focus on a "weak solution" which is not well explained in the body of your Question.

Comment: I cannot see with a shoirt argument why the map is continuous. The map that associates to any $v$ the unique weak solution to $-\text{div}(a(v) \nabla u)=f$ etc.

Comment: No, I use the weak formulation, but I don't see the proper test-function, at the moment.

Comment: Have you proved a well-posedness result for weak solutions? i.e. that if functions $a_1,a_2$ are close in some appropriate norm then the corresponding weak solutions $u_1,u_2$ to $-\mathrm{div}(a_i \nabla u_i ) = f$ are close?